# How can I get the popped li in JQuery Tagit?

Tags: jquery, tag-it

I am now writing a newslist with JQuery Tagit Plugin.(http://jquery.webspirited.com/2011/02/jquery-tagit-a-jquery-tagging-plugin/)

There are a list of news on my web page and each has its own tags. I have to keep track of which tag is added to a news or popped from a news.

Therefore, I have the following codes:

```
<script>
    $('.tagBox').tagit({
        tagsChanged:function(value,action,element){
             alert(value + " is " + action + 
                   " to/from " + element.closest("ul").attr("id"));
        }
    });

</script>
```

And I have the following html:

```
<ul class="tagBox" id="news1">
</ul>

<ul class="tagBox" id="news2">
</ul>
```

These codes work well when I add a tag to a news. However, when I try to delete a tag, the element is null.

So, how can I get the corresponding id of the ul when a tag is popped from it?

Comment: You need to write some code that stores the ID of the `ul` into a variable when you delete the tag (just before you call the plugin's function to actually delete the tag).

Comment: But, where to put these codes?

Comment: Let me just make sure I understand you correct first.. When you say "when I try to delete a tag, the element is null.", you actually mean "when I HAVE DELETED a tag, the element is null.", right?

Comment: And you delete those tags by clicking on the "x" on the right side of the tag in question, yes? .. If yes, then you need to find out which function is called in the plugin's code when you click that "x" (in the source code), and insert some custom code there. (To be honest, that is the dirty way. Better would be to make a custom click function or something where you first execute your own script to store the variable, and then manually call the plugin's function. That way you don't have to change the source code. But I don't know this plugin, so I can't give you any specific advice there.)

Comment: Yes, The tagsChanged api is called when the tag has been deleted. And I can't find an api which is called before that. I will try to bind an onclick function to the "x". Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind an `onmousedown` function to the `tagit-close` class, that stores the ID of the tagBox in question into a variable before the tag is deleted.

The `tagsChanged-event` uses an `onclick/onmouseup`, meaning its called only AFTER you release the mouse-button.
So if you attach an `onmousedown` function to the "x" on the tags (the `<a class="tagit-close">x</a>`), you are sure that you catch the event BEFORE the tag has been deleted.

---

**Script (mockup)**

```
var deletedTagsBox = ""; //global variable

$(".tagit-close").mousedown(function(){
    deletedTagsBox = $(this).closest("ul").attr("id"));
});
```

And then in your original function:

```
$('.tagBox').tagit({
    tagsChanged:function(value,action,element){
         var tagBoxID = "";
         if (element == null) {
             tagBoxID = deletedTagsBox;
         } else {
             tagBoxID = element.closest("ul").attr("id");
         }
         alert(value+" is "+action+" to/from "+tagBoxID);
    }
});
```

Comment: I edited my answer once, about 11 minutes after it was posted, in case you already checked it out before that

Comment: Your solution is right. The problem is solved. Thank you! I also find that binding click function to $(".tagit-close") works as well. I think the reason might be that $(".tagit-close") doesn't handle the delete event itself, but propagates the event to its parents. Thus, the onmouseup function of tagit-close class happened still before the real delete.

Comment: yep, that sounds very plausible, sharp call